# $v, u$ such that $u \circ v = \mathbb{Id}_E$, do we have $\mathbb{P}(v \text{ surjective}) \geq \mathbb{P}(u \text{ injective})$?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

Let be $E, F$ two finite sets.

Let be $v : E \to F, u : F \to E$ such that $u \circ v = \textrm{Id}_E$.

We take the uniform probability, do we have: $\mathbb{P}(v \text{ surjective}) \geq \mathbb{P}(u \text{ injective})$?

I tried to fix an injective app and try to complete it, but I have to fix also a surjective app and see what happens I suppose.

Comment: Hint: The two events are equivalent.

Comment: @darijgrinberg What do you mean by equivalent?

Comment: I mean exactly equal as sets. In other words, $v$ is surjective if and only if $u$ is injective.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I agree on this, but then, I'm confused, wouldn't that mean that probability is equal?

Comment: Yes, it would :)

Comment: Sorry @darijgrinberg my question was not correctly formulated, I understood now. I rather meant, let's take the set of functions $\{(v, u) \mid u \circ v = \textrm{Id}_E \}$ and we take the uniform probability over it, do we still have equality for a randomly sampled $(v, u)$

Comment: Yes. Just check that the two statements are equivalent whenever $u \circ v = \operatorname{Id}_E$.